# How can I access the current user's roles in Orchard from a view page?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I am trying to get the current user's roles in Orchard 1.9.2 from a view.

I tried this snippet of code but it always returns 0 roles:

```
var roles = ((ContentItem)WorkContext.CurrentUser.ContentItem).As<UserRolesPart>().Roles;
```

source: https://www.cloudconstruct.com/blog/retrieving-role-information-in-your-orchard-view-templates

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the using statement is missing?

Try the following code:

```
@using Orchard.ContentManagement

@{
  var roles = WorkContext.CurrentUser.As<Orchard.Roles.Models.UserRolesPart>().Roles;
}
```

**edit 1**

It seems like the user is not authenticated. The line of code posted above creates the following calls:

1. `Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState("CurrentUser")`
2. `Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.FindResolverForState("CurrentUser")`
3. enumerating through a list of `IWorkContextStateProvider`, in this list there should be the following implementation: `Orchard.Security.CurrentUserWorkContext`
4. `Orchard.Security.CurrentUserWorkContext.Get("CurrentUser")`
5. `IAuthenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser()` -> which returns the user when authenticated

So it seems that any of these steps returns without the user. I suggest you create a breakpoint in `Orchard.Environment.WorkContextImplementation.GetState()` to find out where the issue is.

Comment: The using statement is there.  I tried the code to no avail.  It worked for you?

Comment: Does it matter that the view is in a theme?

Comment: @matthewjamesr I think it is an authentication issue, see **edit 1**

Comment: The problem was not with the code.  It was the fact I was doing my testing with the admin account which has no roles.  I was thinking it had the administrator role by default.  I tested with another account and it worked just fine.  Thanks.